# Juniper SRX 210 vlan interface configuration

Tags: networking, cisco-ios, juniper

Dears,

Am new to  networking and i  need your help to solve one issue that i am facing while setting up vlan interface in juniper srx210 device

```
MY-PC ---> Cisco 3750 -- > srx.210 ( vlan interface)
root# show vlans MGMT {
vlan-id 101;
l3-interface vlan.

oot# show interfaces vlan    unit 0 {
family inet {

    address 192.168.10.1/24;
}
show interfaces ge-0/0/1 unit 0 {
family ethernet-switching {
    port-mode trunk;
    vlan {
        members MGMT;
    }
}

root# show security zones security-zone MGMT interfaces {
vlan.101 {
    host-inbound-traffic {
        system-services {
            all;
        }
    }
}
```

}

### cisco Switch

interface FastEthernet1/0/1
switchport trunk allowed vlan 101

---

### PC Port

interface FastEthernet1/0/2
switchport access vlan 101

Comment: Am not able to ping the interface from the PC or cisco switch what could be the wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Is the vlan created on Cisco switch? You have it tagged but you still need to create it. Also have you set encapsulation on the trunk port?

Do you have a policy created between zones on the SRX? Just something simple like below for a test?

```
set security policies from-zone ZONE1 to-zone ZONE2 policy POLICY1 match source-address any
set security policies from-zone ZONE1 to-zone ZONE2 policy POLICY1 match destination-address any
set security policies from-zone ZONE1 to-zone ZONE2 policy POLICY1 match application any
set security policies from-zone ZONE1 to-zone ZONE2 policy POLICY1 then permit
```